# Could someone please explain the difference between setWithObjects and initWithObjects

Tags: objective-c, nsset

So i spent the last hour or so fighting with my code, and eventually discovered that the NSSet I was trying to use was empty. Once I switched from the first line of code to the second, everything worked great. I was just hoping someone could tell me what is wrong with the first line. It compiles just fine, but apparently doesn't do what I'm hoping for.

```
NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [singleOperandOperations initWithObjects: @"cos", @"sin", @"sqrt", nil];
```

v.s.

```
NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"cos", @"sin", @"sqrt", nil];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setWithObjects:` is a so called *convenience constructor*, which in fact does an `alloc` and then an `initWithObjects:`. `setWithObjects:` is just a little less typing. Note that the returned `id` of such a convenience constructor is `autorelease`'d, by convention.

So your first example should be:

```
NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: etc...];
```

And this can be replaced by:

```
NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [NSSet setWithObjects: etc...];
```

Comment: I was wrong about the (NSArray *), as it takes a va_list of arguments. Forgot the exact way to handle this in the method, so I omitted that part again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I do believe that you should `alloc` it. That's what I'd do:

```
NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [[NSSet alloc]initWithObjects: @"cos", @"sin", @"sqrt", nil];
```

That will work. Your other line works too. The difference is only the number of characters that you have to type ;)

Hope it helps

Comment: figures, i tried this at one point: NSSet *singleOperandOperations = [[NSSet alloc] singleOperandOperations initWithObjects: @"cos", @"sin", @"sqrt", nil];

Comment: `singleOperandOperations` should not appear right of the `=` sign. It is the variable that receives the result, no more, so it should not be part of the expression on the right of the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you first example is missing the alloc. But in general calling alloc/init allocates an object which you own while the convenience constructor setWithObjects returns an autoreleased object.